# Not able to connect to a remote SSH server with Elixir

Tags: ssh, elixir, erlang-otp

I have been trying for a while to connect to a remote ssh server with elixir.

This is what I do in IEX:

```
[Macintosh] elixir/logglycious (master|…)> iex                                                                            15-07-20 0:11
Erlang/OTP 17 [erts-6.4] [source] [64-bit] [smp:8:8] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Interactive Elixir (1.0.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> :application.start(:crypto)
{:error, {:already_started, :crypto}}
iex(2)> :application.start(:public_key)
{:error, {:not_started, :asn1}}
iex(3)> :application.start(:asn1)
:ok
iex(4)> :application.start(:public_key)
:ok
iex(5)> :application.start(:ssl)
:ok
iex(6)> :application.start(:ssh)
:ok
iex(7)> :ssh.connect("my.server.co.uk", 22, [ { :user, 'my_username' } ])
{:error, {:options, {:socket_options, [:inet]}}}
iex(8)>
```

First of all, I must say this error message is not helping at all. I received great support from the community on Slack though. Someone suggested to start the inets application too. I did and retried to connect but I got the same error again.

What am I doing wrong ? More importantly, how can I find the solution to such a problem next time ?

[FIXED] There were multiple issues. First the server must be provided between single quotes. Then make sure that your public key does not require a passphrase. If it does, it can be passed as an option to the connect function. Also, it is not necessary to start all the applications I started. `:ssh.start`is the only one I needed.

Comment: One thing I'd suggest--from now on when you report an issue of this sort make sure you test it on the latest stable build.  1.0.5. is the latest stable build of Elixir (as is Erlang 18) and that may make a difference to the error message you get.

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation. I was running on elixir 1.0.4. However I upgraded to 1.0.5 and I got the same error message.

Comment: Note my use of the word _may_ :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If we look at the documentation for [`:ssh.connect/3`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/ssh.html#connect-3) we see that the `host` argument should be a string. Since it's documentation for an erlang function the string means a charlist. Single quotes creates charlist strings, double quotes create utf-8 encoded binary strings. Call the function like this instead: `:ssh.connect('my.server.co.uk', 22, user: 'my_username')`.

Comment: Indeed, it works slightly better now. It still won't work but it is for another reason now:
`{:error, 'Unable to connect using the available authentication methods'}`

Comment: @svarlet are you able to  connect to the server via the `ssh` command line tool? When you managed to do that please share the passed options with us and we will try to translate them.

Comment: You can also use `String.to_char_list/1` to convert from a binary to a char list

Comment: Hey guys, I figured out the problem. I have not been asked for my passphrase (public key auth) for such a long time that I thought I didn't define one for it. I found out that I did and providing it to the options of the connect call made it work.
However, it would be nice to get more details with the errors we get when a connection attempt fails. I could have figured out this earlier and alone. Perhaps there is already a way that I don't know ?