# Erlang ssh connection error: Unable to connect using the available authentication methods

Tags: erlang, elixir

When doing an ssh connection in Elixir, I got this error:

```
:ssh.shell('host address', port_number, user: 'user_name')

{:error, 'Unable to connect using the available authentication methods'}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer was in a comment left by @svarlet on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31507015/not-able-to-connect-to-a-remote-ssh-server-with-elixir).

If your ssh key has a pass-phrase, you need to specify it in the options to the Erlang ssh connect command.

```
:ssh.shell('host address', port_number, user: 'user_name', rsa_pass_phrase: 'ssh_key_passphrase')
```