# SSH Setup Error: Unable to connect using the available authentication methods

Tags: ssh, erlang

I'm using tools which is developed by erlang. When I try to use this tool to connect from Server A to Server C, I got error

```
Unable to connect using the available authentication methods
```

I have a Server B, I use the same tool on Server B, which try to connect to Server C. Everything went well

So I guess the SSH on Server A has some configs cause this error. Could someone help me? which places to check ssh configs. So I can compare configs on Server A and Server B, finding out what's wrong with serverA.

Comment: We need more details here - is it possible to debug the connection from the same machine you are running the code with the -vvv options to ssh?
Also if you set up password on your ssh key, this might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/a/37831251/1383541

Comment: I don't think I can debug ssh, because it is used internally by that tool. When I try to connect with ssh command, it works. And I don't use ssh key in this case, so that problem doesn't fit for this scenario. Could you let me know all ssh configurations, I need to compare one by one. @pennywise